# Ubuntu internet error After Upgrade to 20 from 18

Tags: server, updates, lubuntu, do-release-upgrade, resolv.conf

I just made an upgrade on my ubuntu from ubuntu 18 to ubuntu 20 now I cant even ping google.com  in my server and i have added 8.8.8.8 to my nameserver but i still get the issues.

```
ping google.com: Temporarily failure in name resolution
```

I really need help

Comment: You've tagged Lubuntu, which in 18.04 used a different desktop to later releases & the *release-upgrade* process (as documented) will break things! which is why it wasn't supported.  You however did state 18 & 20 which are not 18.04 & 20.04 & thus have a different upgrade procedure, where no user packages change (a benefit the *year* products, 16 thru 22 use the same user apps unlike say 16.04, 18.04.. 22.04 which cannot!), but Lubuntu being a desktop won't run on 18 or 20 anyway (only 18.04 & 20.04).  I suggest being precise with details & tags.

Comment: If you tagged Lubuntu has it was a 18.04 system (not 18!) you upgraded to 20.04 (not 20!), the documentation said "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) with some mitigation docs initially provided... If you're using a Ubuntu Core 18 server system upgraded to 20 though - that won't be your issue.

Comment: Yes thanks it worked